# jQuery element removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove an element using jQuery.

HTML:

```
 <div class="listContainer" id="listContainer">
        <div class="listItem">
          <div class="name">
            Item Name
          </div>
          <div class="amount">
            <input type="text" class="amountInput" />
          </div>
          <div class="delete">
            <div class="deleteBtn">
              X
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

There are several `listItems`s on the page and each of the `listItem` will be created dynamically using jQuery. I want to delete `amountInput` of specific `listItem` by clicking the `deleteBtn`, so I tried doing:

```
$("#listContainer").on("click", ".deleteBtn", function() {
    $(this).closest(".amountInput").remove();
});
```

This doesn't work. But on the other hand if I try to delete a `listItem` as a whole, the code works:

```
$("#listContainer").on("click", ".deleteBtn", function() {
    $(this).closest(".listItem").remove();
});
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: use this instead `$(this).closest(".listItem").find(".amountInput").remove();` go to parent then find `amountInput`

Comment: That doesn't work because `.closest(...)` looks for ancestors and you're trying to find a sibling.

Answer (score 3):

Because `.closest` propagates to the top of the HTML. So it searches for the first parent that matches your selector. That is why it cannot find .`amountInput`. Because it isn't a parent of your button.

To get `.amountInput` you have to:

```js
$("#listContainer").on("click", ".deleteBtn", function() {
    $(this).closest(".listItem").find('.amountInput').remove();
});
```

This will get the wrapping `.listItem` element and then search it for the `.amountInput` element.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is not correct, use find instead of closest could be helpful in this case, also $(this) in your sample is related to deleteBtn class not to listContainer.

```js
$("#listContainer").on("click", ".deleteBtn", function() {
console.log($(this)) // this here is .deleteBtn not listContainer
 $(this).closest(".listItem").find(".amountInput").remove();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listContainer" id="listContainer">
        <div class="listItem">
          <div class="name">
            Item Name
          </div>
          <div class="amount">
            <input type="text" class="amountInput" />
          </div>
          <div class="delete">
            <div class="deleteBtn">
              X
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This will remove all `.amountInput`